# Where is `AutoImport` from the sbt document which can be used to create a sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

From the document of sbt 0.13.5: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Using-Plugins.html, it mentions an `AutoImport`:

> 3. Define another object that extends `AutoImport`. The contents of this object will be automatically imported in .sbt files, so ensure it only contains important API definitions and types.

I have searched from sbt codebase carefully, but can't find such a class.

Do I miss something? Or the document is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it on the classpath at `sbt.AutoPlugin` and in the sources in the file `Plugins.scala` (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Plugins.scala#L53).

Comment: I think the document is misleading. It's not something can extend `AutoImport`, it's just to define an `object` whose name is exactly `autoImport`